# How to create a simple ngMeteor app?

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I tried to get [ngMeteor](https://github.com/loneleeandroo/ngMeteor) (v0.1.7) working. The JS code runs without errors, however the data binding in the HTML code does not work. This is the code:

JS

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
  ngMeteor.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 'bar';
  }]);
}
```

HTML

```
<head>
  <title>My Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
    [[foo]]
  </div>
</body>
```

This is what i get: [[foo]]

However, I should get: bar

Thoughts?

Comment: After some trial and error... It appears that ngMock is the colporate. In the ngMeteor package folder:

ngMeteor.js

    ngMeteor = angular.module('ngMeteor', [
     'ngMeteor.collections', 
     'ngMeteor.template',
     'hashKeyCopier',
     'ngRoute', 
     'ngTouch',
     'ngAnimate',
     'ngCookies',
     'ngResource',
     'ngSanitize',
     'ngMock'
    ]);

I think ngMock does not play well with angular.bootstrap function, not sure though. However commenting out ngMock solves the problem.